# Blurry image in imageView of android

Tags: android, imageview, image-quality

In my android app i have to set a image in image view.The quality of the original image is good(1920*2000 pixel) but when i add it as image asset and load from mipmap the image becomes blurry[image: blurry image](in a device 480*800 pixel density)but if i  paste it directly into drawable folder then it shows a clear picture[image: clear image] in that device but shows nothing in a tablet display.How can i get a clear picture in all device?

code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView meter=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    meter.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    Bitmap meterIcon =   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   R.mipmap.andes);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = (display.getWidth());
    int height = display.getHeight();

    meter.setMinimumWidth(width);
    meter.setMinimumHeight(height);

    meter.setMaxWidth(width);
    meter.setMaxHeight(height);
    meter.setImageBitmap(meterIcon);






   }
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.example.partha.rotate_check.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
         />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the image quality is reduced is because when you add it as an image asset, the IDE automatically creates a number of new images, for each android resolution. So on a 480p * 800p device screen, android will load the image corresponding to that resolution, which will of course be a lower resolution than the original.

If you want android to always use the original resolution image then you should simply copy the image into the drawable folder as you have done, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: But this process shows nothing in a tablet of 1536*2048 pixel resolution

Comment: Since your image is in Drawable, try changing

Bitmap meterIcon =   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   R.mipmap.andes);

to

Bitmap meterIcon =   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   R.drawable.andes);

Comment: same as before it was

Comment: Try removing that line entirely and instead doing Drawable meterIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.andes); and then doing meter.setImageDrawable(meterIcon);